# -[UIWindow setWindowLevel:] works only once before the window becomes the key window on iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I cannot find anything related to this in documentation. That's what the docs say

> **Changing the Window Level**
>
> Each UIWindow object has a configurable windowLevel property that
>   determines how that window is positioned relative to other windows.
>   For the most part, you should not need to change the level of your
>   application’s windows. New windows are automatically assigned to the
>   normal window level at creation time. The normal window level
>   indicates that the window presents application-related content. Higher
>   window levels are reserved for information that needs to float above
>   the application content, such as the system status bar or alert
>   messages. And although you can assign windows to these levels
>   yourself, the system usually does this for you when you use specific
>   interfaces. For example, when you show or hide the status bar or
>   display an alert view, the system automatically creates the needed
>   windows to display those items.

Seems like no dynamic behavior is supported. Maybe someone knows any workarounds?

The goal is to show the overlaying window above the status bar. Like this

[image]

I used MTStatusBarOverlay (https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay), but since iOS 8.3 there is a system bug in positioning the second window during rotations (https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay/issues/94)

I found out, that adding an instance of MTStatusBarOverlay as a subview of a main window fixes the positioning and rotation problems, but makes the overlay being under the status bar.

[image]

Then I thought that changing the root window's level can place it over the status bar and It worked.

[image]

But this works only in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Any ideas?